# Why can't ping the web address?

Tags: ping

I have registered web000 for free domain name,the info is :

Access your website at http://luofeiyu.comeze.com
Access your website with www. http://www.luofeiyu.comeze.com
Website IP address 31.170.160.111
Server name server47.000webhost.com

```
ping luofeiyu.comeze.com/
ping: unknown host luofeiyu.comeze.com/
ping http://luofeiyu.comeze.com/
ping: unknown host http://luofeiyu.comeze.com/
ping http://www.luofeiyu.comeze.com/
ping: unknown host http://www.luofeiyu.comeze.com/
```

It is  stange that the domain name `luofeiyu.comeze.com` has no ip address?
What is the difference betwwen `http://luofeiyu.comeze.com`  and `http://www.luofeiyu.comeze.com` ,in which situation `http://luofeiyu.comeze.com` is called ,in which situation `http://www.luofeiyu.comeze.com` is called then? What does `www` mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only just registered the domain you may have to wait a while for the information to propagate out to all DNS servers (they often say up to 24 hours but I've rarely seen it take more than a few minutes).

`www.luofeiyu.comeze.com` is a sub-domain of `luofeiyu.comeze.com` - as the domain's owner you can configure the DNS for the domain so that both hostnames point to the same IP address, or to different ones.

The prefix `www` has no special meaning, its just the sub-domain that is often used to host a website for a domain - it looks like your domain registrar has set up 2 hostnames for you, one with this prefix and one without, it's up to you if you keep it this way or not and you can set up as many other sub-domains as you wish for example `ftp.luofeiyu.comeze.com`, `images.luofeiyu.comeze.com` etc

Answer (score 1):

Remove the final slash(/).

```
$ ping luofeiyu.comeze.com 
PING luofeiyu.comeze.com (31.170.162.23) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from luofeiyu.comeze.com (31.170.162.23): icmp_req=1 ttl=50     time=460 ms
64 bytes from luofeiyu.comeze.com (31.170.162.23): icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=397 ms
64 bytes from luofeiyu.comeze.com (31.170.162.23): icmp_req=3 ttl=50 time=445 ms
```